# Ansible loop over nested dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have the following data being returned from an API call

```
"napalm_interfaces_ip": {
    "Vlan5": {
        "ipv4": {
            "10.45.230.250": {
                 "prefix_length": 24
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

How do I debug print the Vlan info, the IP and the prefix length?

This is what I have

```
- debug:
     msg: "Interface: {{ item.key }}, IP: {{ item.value.ipv4 }}"
  with_dict:
     - "{{ napalm_interfaces_ip }}"
```

It produces the below output which shows the IP pointing to another dictionary

> TASK [validate_device_ips : debug]
>
> ---
>
> ok: [] => (item={'value': {u'ipv4': {u'10.45.230.250':
>   {u'prefix_length': 24}}}, 'key': u'Vlan5'}) => {
>      "msg": "Interface: Vlan5, IP: {u'10.45.230.250': {u'prefix_length': 24}}" }

Answer (score 3):

**udpate**

Given the below dictionary for testing

```yaml
  interfaces:
    Vlan5:
      ipv4:
        10.45.230.250:
          prefix_length: 24
        10.45.230.251:
          prefix_length: 24
    Vlan6:
      ipv4:
        10.46.230.250:
          prefix_length: 24
        10.46.230.251:
          prefix_length: 24
```

Q: **"Print the Vlan, IP, and the prefix length."**

A: Get the list of Vlan

```yaml
    vlan: "{{ interfaces|json_query('keys(@)') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    vlan: ['Vlan5', 'Vlan6']
```

Get the lists of IPs and lengths

```yaml
    ipv4: "{{ interfaces|json_query('*.[ipv4.keys(@),
                                        ipv4.*.prefix_length]') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    ipv4:
      - - - 10.45.230.250
          - 10.45.230.251
        - - 24
          - 24
      - - - 10.46.230.250
          - 10.46.230.251
        - - 24
          - 24
```

zip the IPs and lengths

```yaml
    addr: |
      [{% for i in ipv4 %}
      {{ i.0|zip(i.1) }},
      {% endfor %}]
```

gives

```yaml
    addr:
      - - - 10.45.230.250
          - 24
        - - 10.45.230.251
          - 24
      - - - 10.46.230.250
          - 24
        - - 10.46.230.251
          - 24
```

zip the list of Vlan and the lists of addresses, and create a dictionary

```yaml
    intf: "{{ dict(vlan|zip(addr)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
    intf:
      Vlan5:
      - - 10.45.230.250
        - 24
      - - 10.45.230.251
        - 24
      Vlan6:
      - - 10.46.230.250
        - 24
      - - 10.46.230.251
        - 24
```

Now, it is possible to iterate the dictionary with [subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1.0 }} {{ item.1.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ intf|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Vlan5 10.45.230.250 24
  msg: Vlan5 10.45.230.251 24
  msg: Vlan6 10.46.230.250 24
  msg: Vlan6 10.46.230.251 24
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    interfaces:
      Vlan5:
        ipv4:
          10.45.230.250:
            prefix_length: 24
          10.45.230.251:
            prefix_length: 24
      Vlan6:
        ipv4:
          10.46.230.250:
            prefix_length: 24
          10.46.230.251:
            prefix_length: 24

    vlan: "{{ interfaces|json_query('keys(@)') }}"
    #ip4: "{{ interfaces|json_query('*.ipv4.keys(@)') }}"
    #len: "{{ interfaces|json_query('*.ipv4.*.prefix_length') }}"
    ipv4: "{{ interfaces|json_query('*.[ipv4.keys(@),
                                        ipv4.*.prefix_length]') }}"
    addr: |
      [{% for i in ipv4 %}
      {{ i.0|zip(i.1) }},
      {% endfor %}]
    intf: "{{ dict(vlan|zip(addr)) }}"
      
  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          vlan: {{ vlan }}
          ipv4:
            {{ ipv4|to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(2) }}
          addr:
            {{ addr|to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(2) }}
          intf:
            {{ intf|to_nice_yaml(indent=2)|indent(2) }}

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1.0 }} {{ item.1.1 }}"
      loop: "{{ intf|dict2items|subelements('value') }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.key }}"
```

---

**origin**

[dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) should help:

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "IP: {{ item.key }} prefix_length: {{ item.value.prefix_length }}"
      loop: "{{ napalm_interfaces_ip.Vlan5.ipv4 | dict2items }}"
```

*with_dict* works too

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "IP: {{ item.key }} prefix_length: {{ item.value.prefix_length }}"
      with_dict: "{{ napalm_interfaces_ip.Vlan5.ipv4 }}"
```

An example of how to loop the interfaces is below

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost
      gather_facts: false
      vars:
        interfaces:
          - Vlan0:
              ipv4:
                10.45.230.250:
                  prefix_length: 24
          - Vlan1:
              ipv4:
                10.45.230.251:
                  prefix_length: 24
          - Vlan2:
              ipv4:
                10.45.230.252:
                  prefix_length: 24
      tasks:
        - name: List selected variables
          vars:
            msg: |
              vlan {{ item|dict2items|json_query('[].key') }}
              ip {{ item|dict2items|json_query('[].value.ipv4|[0]')|dict2items|json_query('[].key') }}
              prefix {{ item|dict2items|json_query('[].value.ipv4|[0]')|dict2items|json_query('[].value.prefix_length') }}
          debug:
            msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
          loop: "{{ interfaces }}"
```

It is possible to simplify the structure of the data

```yaml
    - hosts: localhost
      vars:
        interfaces:
          - Vlan0:
              ipv4: "10.45.230.250"
              prefix_length: "24"
          - Vlan1:
              ipv4: "10.45.230.251"
              prefix_length: "24"
          - Vlan2:
              ipv4: "10.45.230.252"
              prefix_length: "24"
      tasks:
        - name: List selected variables
          vars:
            msg: |
              vlan {{ item|dict2items|json_query('[].key') }}
              ip {{ item|dict2items|json_query('[].value.ipv4') }}
              prefix {{ item|dict2items|json_query('[].value.prefix_length') }}
          debug:
            msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
          loop: "{{ interfaces }}"
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir...thanks you for the response. I actually need to print the interface name, i.e. Vlan5 and then extract the nested IP information and prefix. Also there could be multiple vlans with IPs so I need to find a way to loop through this.

Comment: [Have you tried? What were the results? Any errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes I tried however that is not the solution I was going for. The vlan cannot be emberded in the loop because that information changes with each API call. Also there can be multiple  vlans with IP returned so that has to be considered

Comment: Thank you very much for looking again into this. I appreciate your response. I tested using the code above and the error message I get back. It seems like it won't work with the dictionary information I receive from the system